# Guava's EventBus - visibility of @Subscribe

Tags: java, guava, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

Annotation from interface methods are not inherited to objects implementing that interface, afaik. [SO search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=interface%20annotation%20inherit).

I wanted to use an interface together with Guava's EventBus, which requires that an object has a callback method annotated with `@Subscribe`.
I was wondering if I could simply put that annotation into the interface and let the object implement that listener interface. According to [above](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=interface%20annotation%20inherit), this should **not** work. However, it *does work* (see code below).

Why?

My machine is Java 1.8.0_151 (32 bit) with Windows 7.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus;
import com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe;

/**
 * This test should fail, but... it works!
 */
public class EventTests {


    @Test
    public void test_events_are_heard() {

        MyListener listener = new MyListener();
        DeafListener deafListener = new DeafListener();
        EventBus bus = new EventBus();
        bus.register(listener);
        bus.register(deafListener);
        bus.post(new MyEvent());
        assertEquals(1, listener.eventCount);     // ok
        assertEquals(0, deafListener.eventCount);   // ok
    }

    // this interface includes the @Subscribe annotation
    private interface Listener {
        @Subscribe
        public void onEvent(MyEvent event);
    }

    // this interface does not include the @Subscribe annotation
    private interface NoListener {
        public void onEvent(MyEvent event);
    }

    // just something different from Object
    private static class MyEvent {
    }       

    // implementation of "Listener" (with @Subscribe in interface)
    private static class MyListener implements Listener {
        int eventCount = 0;
        @Override
        public void onEvent(MyEvent event) {
            eventCount ++;
        }
    }

    // IDENTICAL implementation as above, but of "NoListener" 
    // (without @Subscribe in interface)
    private static class DeafListener implements NoListener {
        int eventCount = 0;
        @Override
        public void onEvent(MyEvent event) {
            eventCount ++;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You are right... and wrong.

You are right in that the [`@Subscribe`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/24.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/eventbus/Subscribe.html) annotation is not inherited. You can check it by having such a test `MyListener.class.getMethod("onEvent", MyEvent.class).getAnnotation(Subscribe.class) != null`.

However, it *feels* right to have a subscribing method to be registered if it's defined in the interface.

So [this was discussed at length within the Guava team](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/783) in the past and the Principle of Least Surprise made it that if any of the declaring methods is annotated, then their registered implementations are subscribed.

I have to admit that I checked [the documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained) and [the Javadoc](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/24.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.html) and didn't see anything about your question specifically, even though it feels a necessary mention. I remembered the discussion from years ago and had to find the answer in closed issues.

Comment: Wow, I really wish this was documented, so I'd know it's "correct" to use it that way (although this entire bus is designed to work without interfaces, I read that discussion somewhere).
Having it documented would also probably imply a change note when this behaviour changes, right? Thanks a lot!